# Installing xlsx package in R studio

Tags: r, xlsx

I tried to install xlsx package in R studio,but its returning some error. Can't identify what is the issue. Please help with.Here's the error log

```
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/lenovo/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘xlsx’ is not available (for R version 3.5.1)
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/PACKAGES'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I deal with "package 'xxx' is not available (for R version x.y.z)" warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-for-r-version-x-y-z-wa)

Comment: Can you open the URL in your web browser?

Comment: Not recommended but try `install.packages("xlsx",dependencies=T)`